# <%=PerformSomeFunction()%> What's Going on Here?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I really didn't know how to ask this question in a simple fashion.

I need to display a Client name on a page in several places and they're not always visible at the same time.

The solution I originally had was 3 Label Controls (uxClientName1, uxClientName2 and uxClientName3) and I'd populate them in my code behind when I needed them.

```
uxClientName1 = CurrentClient.ClientName
```

A colleague suggested I use the following solution. On my page I would have this wherever I need it...

```
<%=DisplayClientName()%>
```

and in my code behind I would have this...

```
Protected Function DisplayClientName() As String

    Return CurrentClient.ClientName

End Function
```

This is great because it's doing exactly what I want with no repeated code but I don't really understand how it works or exactly what's going on.

Any explanations?

EDIT: This is my Client Property on the page...

```
Private Property CurrentClient() As Client
    Get
        If ViewState("CurrentClient") Is Nothing Then
            '   No such value in view state, take appropriate action.
            ViewState("CurrentClient") = New Client
            Return CType(ViewState("CurrentClient"), Client)
        Else
            Return CType(ViewState("CurrentClient"), Client)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Client)
        ViewState("CurrentClient") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Classic ASP, thats the way it all used to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx).

> Embedded code blocks must be written
>   in the page's default language. For
>   example, if the page's @ Page
>   directive contains the attribute
>   language="VB", the page will use the
>   Visual Basic compiler to compile code
>   in any script block marked with
>   runat="server" and any in-line code in
>   <% %> delimiters.
>
> Embedded code blocks are supported in
>   ASP.NET Web pages primarily to
>   preserve backward compatibility with
>   older ASP technology. In general,
>   using embedded code blocks for complex
>   programming logic is not a best
>   practice, because when the code is
>   mixed on the page with markup, it can
>   be difficult to debug and maintain. In
>   addition, because the code is executed
>   only during the page's render phase,
>   you have substantially less
>   flexibility than with code-behind or
>   script-block code in scoping your code
>   to the appropriate stage of page
>   processing.

Some uses for embedded code blocks:

- Setting the value of a control or markup element to a value returned by a function
- Embedding a calculation directly into the markup or control property.

Here is a [list of all inline ASP.NET tags](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok thanks. So what would be a suitable replacement for this kind of functionality. It doesn't seem quite right to have 3 label and populate them all in different places.

Comment: If you're doing fine with it, use it. It's not bad in general to use embedded code blocks, but often there might be better ways. What is `CurrentClient`?

Comment: CurrentClient is a instance of a Client Class that I created.

Comment: @Westicle: what is a Client Class and where/how is it initialized? If we'd have more background informations, we might suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Tim The Client class is a simple class I created to represent a client that works for my business. On page load I take a Client's ID from a querystring, create an instance of the Client class and store it in viewstate via a page property. I've added this to my question above.

Comment: @Westicle: The client is not the curent user, is he? Then you should store him in Session instead. The client-class is serializable? Otherwise you can't store it in ViewState. Are you using MasterPages? Is so and your labels are in the same place on every page, you could place them outside of the contentpage and inside of the NasterPage. Then you also need to set it at one place.

Comment: @Tim no the Client class simply represents a business in the real world that does work for by company. The user of the application will be one of our own staff. Yes the Client class is serializable. I am using a MasterPage but the labels only exist on this one page but I have 3 labels on different parts of the page that all need to display the same thing. They are not all visible at the same time though and are contained in separate Panel Controls.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is served, ASP.NET will try and call that function, and then it will write it's return value to the response stream.

This will only happen once

```
<%= func() %>
```

means call `func()` on the server-side when you evaluate the page

Answer (score 0):

`<%=DisplayClientName()%>` is shorthand for `<%Response.Write(DisplayClientName())%>`. It is simply writing the return value from the answer to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Code between `<%` and `%>` is executed on the server side. The `=` sign means that the result of the method will be output to the page. So essentially `<%=DisplayClientName()%>` in your page will be replaced with the return value of `DisplayClient`.